# How to send the data of 2 jdbc readers to one flat file using Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I need to write a job in which i have to read the database 2 times.

First query returns only one record and i need to send this record as the header of my flat file.
Second query returns a set of records that i need to write in same flat file.

I tried to create a **compositewriter** for it and within that i provided two **flatFileItemWriter** and set same resource name for both the flatFileItemWriters. But this is resulting in a error that ***resource alread exists***.

Can anyone tell me the approach that i should follow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Write into two different files with `FlatFileItemWriter` and in a 3rd step append the files.

Answer (score 0):

Write your bean taking into account of your second query which returns a set of records.
For the header part, you give a [FlatFileHeaderCallback](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileHeaderCallback.html) as a property to your FlatFileItemWriter and get the header record there.

```
public class MyFileHeaderCallback implements FlatFileHeaderCallback {
    @Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("#I have this line from a query");
    }
}

<bean id="headerCallback" class="com.file.MyFileHeaderCallback" />

<bean id="productItemWriter" class="org.*.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
<property name="headerCallback" ref="headerCallback" />
<!-- other necessary methods for your Writer -->
</bean>
```